Why normally writting numbers without dollar sign in mathSE is not looking proper in my desktop?
I don't know whether this question is appropriate here. But I am facing a technical issue regarding the font in MathSE. I am writing this  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 in the writing box of this website without dollar $ sign (i.e. without latex environment) But it looks different in the draft portion from my mobile and desktop. In mobile it looks quite okay. 
But it my desktop(windows 10) it looks very much improper. 1, 2 are too small; 6 , 8 shifted up. 7, 9 shifted down.
why how can I improve it? (also if this question is not appropriate in this site, please suggest where should i ask it)

It's because Mathematics Stack Exchange uses Georgia (on Windows computers), and by default this font uses "old style" numerals, aka "text figures".  So, there's nothing wrong or "improper" here.
I'm not sure if you can do anything about this TBH. Georgia does have both variants but I don't know if you can use these on MathSE. Different fonts can use different styles of numerals, some have standard numerals, some have old style numerals, and some have both variants.  Here are the two variants that Georgia has.

There's an entry in Wikipedia regarding these style of numerals if you are interested Text figures.

My doubts get cleared. I more thing Can you identify what is that font in my mobile  (android 11-Samsung). It is not Georgia, neither of the old and new version you sent in the ans if I am able to closely look at it. Then what is the name of this font?

@Skdmg - No idea sorry.  Different devices and operating systems might have different fonts. There's no real way to answer this without access to your device.

They are simply different typefaces. Every typeface may change how any glyph (character) appears.
Each of your 4 examples of 1234.....  are displayed in a different font.
There is no such thing as "normal writing numbers". Number characters, like any type character, are all design to match a specific typeface. Numbers for Times New Roman will always look different than numbers for Helvetica.
